# Calling class method from another class method

Tags: c#, class

From my main code I'm calling a method of a class `meth2` which calls another method from another class `meth1`. It is important for me to respect this structure.
These methods make an assignment of values that are previously defined in the classes but I am not able to get a proper result in my command window (just a `0` instead of a `132`). I assume I'm missing something.

Does anybody has an idea? Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace workingWithClasses
{
    class meth1
    {
        public int op1;

        public int multiply(int mult)
        {
            return op1 = 44 * mult;
        }
    }

    class meth2
    {
        public int CallFuncsClass(int multiplicator)
        {
            return m1.multiply(int multiplicator);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            meth1 m1 = new meth1();
            meth2 m2 = new meth2();

            m2.CallFuncsClass(3);
            int result_m1 = m1.op1;         

            Console.WriteLine(opm1);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is opm1? I do not see the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace workingWithClasses
{
    public class meth1
    {
        public int op1;

        public int multiply(int mult)
        {
            return op1 = 44 * mult;
        }
    }

    public class meth2
    {
        meth1 m1 = new meth1();
        public int CallFuncsClass(int multiplicator)
        {
            return m1.multiply( multiplicator);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           meth2 m2 = new meth2();

           int result_m2 = m2.CallFuncsClass(3);
           Console.WriteLine(result_m2);

           Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code won't compile, right? This line `return m1.multiply(int multiplicator);` is out of the place. You need to define what is `m1`.  I guess you are looking for dependency injection. You can do this via constructor, so

```
class meth2
{
    private meth1 _m1;

    meth2(meth1 m1)
    {
        if(m1 == null) throw new ... // check input params

        _m1 = m1;
    }

    public int CallFuncsClass(int multiplicator)
    {
        return _m1.multiply(int multiplicator);
    }
}
```

The usage will be

```
meth1 m1 = new meth1();
meth2 m2 = new meth2(m1);

m2.CallFuncsClass(3);
```

#### Bonus points

- Name your classes correctly, instead of `meth1` it should be something like `Calculator`
- Don't use public fields: `public int op1;`. It should be private
- Usually you would want your classes to be `public`, by default the class is `internal`. In this way you can use it outside a single library
- Check parameters for correct value, throw exception if something is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Make multiply static on class meth1:

```
public static int multiply(int mult)
```

Also don't use 'op1', just return the result of the operation.

Call like this:

```
return meth1.multiply(int multiplicator);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace workingWithClasses
{
    class meth1
    {
        public int op1;

        public int multiply(int mult)
        {
            return op1 = 44 * mult;
        }
    }

    class meth2
    {
        public int CallFuncsClass(int multiplicator)
        {
            meth1 m1=new meth1();
            return m1.multiply(multiplicator);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            meth2 m2 = new meth2();

            int result_m1=m2.CallFuncsClass(3);

            Console.WriteLine(result_m1);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am still getting 0 as result. The variable assigned in `meth1` is not recognized in the main file

Comment: @user3252535 check my updated answer. updated code **int result_m1=m2.CallFuncsClass(3);**

Answer (score -1):

If you want to call methods from `meth1` from within `meth2` like that (without creating an object of type `meth1`) you need to make `multiply()` static.

This will allow it to be used in the manner you're using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace workingWithClasses
{
    class meth1
    {
        //note statics
        static int op1;

        static int multiply(int mult)
        {
            return op1 = 44 * mult;
        }
    }

    class meth2
    {
        public int CallFuncsClass(int multiplicator)
        {
            //access to multiply() is valid here
            return meth1.multiply(multiplicator);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            meth1 m1 = new meth1();
            meth2 m2 = new meth2();

            m2.CallFuncsClass(3);
            int result_m1 = m1.op1;         

            Console.WriteLine(opm1);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: basically this line is wrong `return meth1.multiply(int multiplicator);`. You must have to write like `return meth1.multiply(multiplicator);`